# Purpose of Surrogate Key

Tags: sql, data-warehouse

I wonder why developer create their own surrogate key as primary key in their dataware house although table has aldready primary key.

In telecommunication system, there is gsm_no or account_id as primary key. Why developers in dataware house who take these table from another system add new primary key for their system by creating surrogate key (such as customer_sk)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second, but not less important reason is because very often primary keys are not integers. It's hard to find that ERPs or CRMs don't have meaningfull PK's in varchar type. Performance does metter!

Third one, if you're implementing SCD type 1, you can store historical values of dimension (i.e. employee changed department).
And, as our SO friend says, multiple sources.

Answer (score 1):

It's a generally accepted "good practice"; data warehouses should be isolated from production systems in terms of dependencies, and that includes isolation from existing primary keys.  Probably the best reason for this is key re-use in different source systems; if a data warehouse is pulling from multiple sources, or the initial source is swapped out with a different source, you explicitly define mapping relationships between sources at the DW level as opposed to relying on just a key.

http://christianvdheever.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/surrogate-keys-and-foreign-keys-in-a-dimensional-data-model/